# Passing arguments to Static constructor with Intent

Tags: java, android

Hello I am new to Java and I am trying to do something so I need some help; I have a constructor as such :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    access();
    key(args[0], args[1]);
}
```

and I am trying to pass the values for keys from the UI of my android Interface in main activity as such:

```
private void enter(String keycode) {
    String[] args = {"keycode", "pin"};
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.main());
    myIntent.putExtra ("keycode", "pin"); //Optional parameters
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

But I am getting an error which is saying, the type main(String[]) is not applicable to the argument() in eclipse.
The keycode is from the onclick listener and I statically declared the pin. The key and pin are supposed to be the values of arg[0] and arg[1] in main. I have not run it or anything, all I need is just a correct syntax to call the main static method from the "enter" on click listener construct.
Thank you in advance. So in general, I have two parameters that main method takes:
access(); // all parameters are static defined
key(arg[0] , arg[1]);
I need to pass those args using intent or some method that would start my activity. All in the same class. Sorry about my ignorance if any.
BTW emulator of interface runs fine, I just need to access the main(strings [] args), just that part.

Answer (score 3):

1)There is no such thing as a static constructor.  The entire concept is an oxymoron.

2)Android doesn't use main functions.

3)That's not how you start an activity anyway.  The second parameter of Intent's constructor is a Class, not a function call- which isn't legal java anyway as function pointers don't exist.

What you're doing is so confused I'm not even sure how to fix it.  You need to start from scratch with android tutorials on what an activity is and how an android app works.

Comment: Like I said I am new to the concept and I am doing a fair share of reading. I might have jumbled up words, I meant my method main() is static, which I posted above, and I am trying to enter the remaining program by accessing the method main(string [] args). Lets forget all the advanced concepts now, can you just tell me how to pass arguments to that main block of code and call those functions within it to start my activity.

Comment: You don't use main in Android.  At all.  That's a desktop app java concept.  You really need to start again from books/tutorials-  there's too much wrong to explain what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Also, the biggest one-  this isn't javascript like you tagged it, its java.  Two totally separate, unrelated languages.

Comment: Thank you! I keep pressing enter for newline, I edited my response.

Comment: If android doesn't use main,  can I  rename it as class helper just another member class? would changing the name from main make a difference?

Comment: I cant delete the tag, if there's nothing further you'd help me with I can remove the post all together. Thanks

Comment: Can anyone give me an arbitrary way to call this function, if arg[0] had the VALUE2 and arg[1] has VALUUE2 assigned to them respectively.


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    access();
    key(args[0], args[1]);
    }

Comment: Really, you need to go back to basics of Android.  Your approach makes 0 sense for either desktop or Android Java, the mix of the two makes it so I can't even give good advice.

Comment: Okay thanks! can you help me delete this post please? I cant seem to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to find a solution to my problem. Firstly, the idea of using "itent" to start my activity came about when I tried to call a different class which I imported into main activity as a functional thread.  I really didn't need to when I combined the scripts I was trying to call. 
I only asked a simple question on how to call a static method which was what I needed to do.
The way I solved it was just to use the following lines (excerpt), after setting up the onclick listener button for keycode and statically defining the pin, as it relates to my question:

```
private void enter(String keycode) {
try {
String[] arguments = new String[] { keycode, pin};
MainActivity.main(arguments);
```

That was it, and my emulator and activity works just fine. And by the way android was able to use main functions, because it works just fine.
To all the experts who easily get uneasy with a newbie trying to ask a question, I thought they must have started from somewhere, and there's many ways to skin a cat not just thinking because you try to do something a certain way it wont work. Patience helps people to learn.